# SSRS: How to add an condition in the expression while counting rows?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I need help with writing a conditional expression for counting specific rows of the dataset using which I determine to make a textbox visbile

```
DataSet_Example
Name  value   Level 
ABC   12345   PG1
DEF   45677   PG2
FEG   98098   PG1
```

I want to count the rows based on the level. Something Like the one below
iff(CountRows("DataSet_Example").Level == PG1 < 1)

How do I do it in SSRS expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You need insert a row group for "Level" and then set your visibility expression for each row to the following:

=IIF(CountRows("Level") > 1 , condition if true, condition if false )